# Increment an ID field in a sql server after insert trigger for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to use an after insert trigger to make my own identity column.  The reason is that I need to keep the IDs unique for each site.  The 1st site will used IDs 1 - 10,000 the next site will use IDs from 10,000 - 20,000.

Each site has there own server and the tables are synced at regular intervals. The trigger will be slightly different at each site.  The only difference is the max number that it looks for to increment.

If you look at the commented out code you can see what I did to make it work for single record inserts.  But I need to support multiple record inserts as well.  The last update statement was my second attempt.  It runs fine but only increments for the first record and all other records in that insert get that same ID value.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ID_AfterInsert] ON [dbo].[TestTable]
AFTER insert,
UPDATE
AS
--IF ((SELECT ID from inserted) is NULL)
BEGIN

--DECLARE @ID Bigint, @autoID Bigint
--SET NOCOUNT ON;
--SET @ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 as ID From TestTable Where ID >= 10000 And ID < 20000)
--If (@ID is NULL)
--  BEGIN
--    SET @ID = 10000
--  END
--SET @autoID = (SELECT AutoID FROM inserted)

UPDATE TestTable set ID = COALESCE((SELECT MAX(ID)+1 as ID From TestTable Where ID >= 10000 And ID < 20000),10000) FROM Inserted i WHERE TestTable.AutoID=i.autoID And i.ID is null
End
Go
```

Comment: Please please please -- **don't do this!** The `SELECT MAX(ID)+1` approach is **very likely to produce duplicates!** The only reliable way to do this is to use a `INT IDENTITY` column in your table - then the database makes sure it's not generating duplicates for you!

Comment: I probably should have added these are small, rarely added to, lookup tables.  The largest one currently only has 250 records after 3 years of use.  Also because the sites operate independently and then sync there data, I have to maintain different IDs and it can't be done with the IDENTITY since it always goes from the largest number in the field.